# Transformation of random variable and domain change

Tags: probability, transformation, density-function

So i was wondering about this for a while. Given a random variable $X$ with density $f_X(x)=e^{-x}$ where $x\geq 0$. consider another random variable, $Y=\log X$. Is the domain of $Y$ given by $[0,\infty)$? If yes, why? thanks :)!

Y

Comment: Well $Y = \ln X > -\infty$. You can also find this distribution, $F_Y(y) = P(Y \le y) = P(\ln X \le y) = P(X \le e^y) = F_X(e^y)$ so $f_Y(y) = f_X(e^y)e^y$.

Hence,
$$ f_Y(y) = e^{y-e^y} $$

Comment: hmm, i understand how you get the distribution, but what i am confused about is why we let $0$ in the domain of $Y$. Am i not seeing something?

Comment: I don't follow, $X = 1$ is in the domain, so $Y = \ln 1 = 0$ is in the domain of $Y$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a drawing of the function $Y=\log X$ and see that Y domain is the X imagine, thus $Y \in \mathbb{R}$

Using the fundamental transformation theorem you get

$$f_Y(y)=f_X(g^{-1}(y))\cdot |\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)|=e^{y-e^y}$$

Comment: but $log(0)$ is not defined, right?

Comment: @YousefKaddoura yes but $P(X=k)=0$ for any k as the distribution is continuous. Thus you can consider you $X \in (0;+\infty)$

Comment: So, the domain of a random variable is ultimately described by the distribution function?

Comment: @YousefKaddoura: the domain of a transformed rv is described by the transformation function